# awk - join last column with next line first column

Tags: awk

I want to join last column of the line with the next line first column. For example:

```
cat FILE
12  15
22  25
32  35
42  45
```

to join like this:

```
15  22
25  32
35  42
```

`15` (last column) joined with `22` (first column of next line).

My solution is: `tr '\n' '@' < FILE | tr '\t' '\n' | grep '@' | grep -v '@$' | tr '@' '\t'` 
But there might be simple `awk` command to do this.

Comment: And where do `12` (first row) and `45` (last row) go?

Comment: They are discarded as there is nothing to join them with (this is why I am using `grep -v '@$'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{ 
  for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 2) 
    print $i, $(i + 1) 
    }' RS= OFS=\\t infile
```

With *bash*:

```
a=($(<infile));printf '%s\t%s\n' ${a[@]:1:${#a[@]}-2}
```

With *zsh*:

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' ${$(<infile):1:-1}
```

Comment: RS= sets the record separator to an empty string. In this case, given the sample data, the entire file is considered one record.

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if (NR==1) {a=$2} else {print a,$1;a=$2}}' file
15      22
25      32
35      42
```

- `'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` set file separator as tab.
- `{if (NR==1) {a=$2}` for first line just store 2nd field.
- `else {print a,$1;a=$2}}` in the rest of cases print 2nd field of previous row and 1st field of current. This way we do not print last record.

Comment: Is it possible to make columns tab separated? `$1"\t"$2` gave an error. And `OFS` doesn't work here either.

Comment: OK now it's completely done, see the `OFS` option in the `BEGIN`.

Answer (score 2):

[**Dimitre Radoulov**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167895/1066031) has the solution but if we're golfing:

```
awk '$1=$NF=X;1' RS= file|xargs -n2
15 22
25 32
35 42
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR!=1{print $1,p} {p=$2}'
```